# Scrapy item metadata?

Tags: scrapy

My spider yields two types of items, which are then processed by a pipeline. Is there a way for the pipeline to identify each type of item (other than through the keys). Some sort of metadata type or title field?

Answer (score 1):

In your `pipelines.py`:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    if isinstance(item, YourItemType1):
        # code to process Item Type 1
```